# PHP returning value of 1

Tags: php

i still cannot get this review system to work properly.
i know the average rating is 3.57 but as soon as i add the if() all i am getting is an output of 1?

```
// collect 5 lastest reviews for viewing
$sql = "SELECT AVG(rating) FROM reviews WHERE review_id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $AvgReview = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    // Here we have the toatal row count
    $AvgReviews = $AvgReview[0];
if($AvgReviews = 1){
    echo '1star';
}
//next else is new
else if($AvgReviews >= 1){
    echo '2star';
}
//next else is new
else if($AvgReviews >= 2){
    echo '3star';
}
//next else is new
else if($AvgReviews >= 3){
    echo '4star';
}
//next else is new
else if($AvgReviews >= 4){
    echo '5star';
}
```

Comment: you need to use `==` for a comparison.  `if($AvgReviews == 1){`

Comment: `if($AvgReviews = 1){` should be `if($AvgReviews == 1){`

Comment: `($AvgReviews = 1)` should be `($AvgReviews < 1)`

Comment: and the minimal example should be `$v=0; if($v = 1){ echo "oops"; }`

Comment: You will also want to reverse your if/else if checking, as since `3.57` meets the criteria for `else if($AvgReviews >= 1)` you will get  `2star` instead of `4star`.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting '1star' because you are assigning a value of 1 to $AvgReviews.
Change your code to compare the value.

```
if ($AvgReviews == 1) {
```

Additionally, you need to reverse your code or you will end up getting 1 or 2 stars, only.
I would recommend to change it like that:

```
if ($AvgReviews > 4) {
    echo '5star';
}
else if($AvgReviews > 3) {
    echo '4star';
}
else if($AvgReviews > 2) {
    echo '3star';
}
else if($AvgReviews > 1) {
    echo '2star';
}
else {
    echo '1star';
}
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Comment: thanks for your help, but im now getting 2

Comment: As mentioned in the comments already, you need to change the order of your ifs, because every value that is higher than 1 will match ($AvgReviews >= 1)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're assigning `1` to `$AvgReviews`.  The [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (`=`) takes the value on the right-hand side, assigns it to the name on the left-hand side, and then returns the value that was assigned.  In this case, that's always `1`, which PHP interprets as `true`.

Use the [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead:

```
if($AvgReviews == 1){
    echo '1star';
}
```